# Showing Javascript variables in a modal

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, modal-dialog

On my website I'm trying to make a modal that informs the user of their username (generated from their forename and surname) and informs the users that they have been added to a moderation que for their account to be approved. I create the account within a php file called with ajax and then use JSON to feedback a integer that informs the javascript if the process was successful and if so what the user's username is. My modal opens fine if the account was created and the information is displayed about the approval process, however I cannot seems to get it to display the section with the username in. Can you try and see where I'm going wrong.

**Javascript**

```
var RegisterSuccess = new Array();
var RegisterSuccess = JSON.parse(Feedback);
if (RegisterSuccess[0] == 0){
    $('#mdlInfo').html('<p>Your account has been created under the username: "<strong><span id="spnUsername"></span></strong>". You <strong>must</strong> remember this as you will require it to login to your account.</p>');
    $('#mdlInfo').html('<p>Your account has also been added to a moderation que. You must wait until a member of staff activates your account!</p>');
    $('#spnUsername').html(RegisterSuccess[1]);
    $("#mdlRegister").modal("show");
```

**PHP Output code**

$Feedback = json_encode(array($RegisterSuccess, $username));

echo $Feedback;

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just return a proper json_encoded array from PHP? No need to assign a variable, just do 
`echo json_encode(["success"=>"true","username"=>"$username"]);` 
and in the javascript (no need to assign the `RegisterSuccess` as array either), just do
`var returnValue = JSON.parse(Feedback);`
(you should avoid calling the variable `RegisterSuccess` - chose a neutral name so you can use it for both success and error without issues. Then just do

```
$('#mdlInfo').html('<p>Your account has been created under the username: <strong><span id="spnUsername">'+returnValue['username']+'</span></strong>. You <strong>must</strong> remember this as you will require it to login to your account.</p><p>Your account has also been added to a moderation que. You must wait until a member of staff activates your account!</p>');
$("#mdlRegister").modal("show");
```

Comment: Do I need to define the data as Feedback in the PHP script you can I just keep the data parameter it in the ajax line as Feedback to label it as that?    $.post('functions/php/fncregister.php', {forename: forename, surname: surname, password: password, passwordR: passwordR}, function(Feedback) {

Comment: You can name it whatever. It just takes whatever is returned from the PHP-script. Personally I just call it `(data)`.

Comment: Roger, that seems to have work perfectly. Thanks for your help and explanation, a lot of the documentation for this kind of thing isn't very clear!

Comment: Btw - the reason it probably didn't work at all with the code you had in the beginning was that you declared `$('#mdlInfo').html()` twice - the second time would overwrite the first. (.html() replaces all content in the element)

Comment: Thanks man! That will solve me a lot of head scratching in the future! I'll continue doing it as you showed before with several tags in the same line.

Comment: Yeah, as long as you're outputting it in the same call, and/or in the same element, just put it all in the same one.